# Google Chat API: How do I switch between Cards v1 and Cards v2?

Tags: google-chat-api

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/cards-v1), Cards v1 is deprecated, and Cards v2 seems to be much more feature-rich.

But when I use the Cards v2 syntax, the API complains about unknown or missing fields. How can I tell the Google servers that I want to use the v2 API? The documentation does not seem to tell anything about that.

All tutorials that I can find seem to use Cards v1 only. I'm mostly following [the official tutorial in Python](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth/service-accounts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to send message with card v2 with this syntax:

```
"cards_v2": [[{
      "card_id": "addContact",
      "card": {}
}]
```

Request:

```
POST https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/space_name/messages
{
    
    "cards_v2": [{
      "card_id": "addContact",
      "card": {
        "header": {
          "title": "Rolodex",
          "subtitle": "Manage your contacts!",
          "imageUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/contacts_48dp.png",
          "imageType": "CIRCLE"
        },
        "sections": [
          {
            "widgets": [
              {
                "buttonList": {
                  "buttons": [
                    {
                      "text": "Add Contact",
                      "onClick": {
                        "action": {
                          "function": "openDialog",
                          "interaction": "OPEN_DIALOG"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }]
  ,
    "thread": {
     "name": "spaces/space_name/threads/thread_name"
  }
}
```

Taken from here:
https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/dialogs?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I'm eagerly waiting for 15 rep to be able to upvote your answer :-)

Comment: Somehow we still can't make the dialog open from the button click.
@GeorgWicke-Arndt did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JSON schema to use v2 cards;

```
{
  "cardsV2": [
    {
      "cardId": "unique-card-id",
      "card": {
        "header": {
          "title": "Sasha",
          "subtitle": "Software Engineer",
          "imageUrl":
          "https://developers.google.com/chat/images/quickstart-app-avatar.png",
          "imageType": "CIRCLE",
          "imageAltText": "Avatar for Sasha",
        },
        "sections": [
          {
            "header": "Contact Info",
            "collapsible": true,
            "uncollapsibleWidgetsCount": 1,
            "widgets": [
              {
                "decoratedText": {
                  "startIcon": {
                    "knownIcon": "EMAIL",
                  },
                  "text": "sasha@example.com",
                }
              },
              {
                "decoratedText": {
                  "startIcon": {
                    "knownIcon": "PERSON",
                  },
                  "text": "<font color=\"#80e27e\">Online</font>",
                },
              },
              {
                "decoratedText": {
                  "startIcon": {
                    "knownIcon": "PHONE",
                  },
                  "text": "+1 (555) 555-1234",
                }
              },
              {
                "buttonList": {
                  "buttons": [
                    {
                      "text": "Share",
                      "onClick": {
                        "openLink": {
                          "url": "https://example.com/share",
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "text": "Edit",
                      "onClick": {
                        "action": {
                          "function": "goToView",
                          "parameters": [
                            {
                              "key": "viewType",
                              "value": "EDIT",
                            }
                          ],
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  ],
                }
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    }
  ],
}
```

[visit Google chat docs for more](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/cards)